# prepareForSegue:sender: fails to alter property on destination VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, viewcontroller

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
I have two modes -- edit and add.
From VC1, when add button is touched it segues to VC2 and the user can fill out details and add an entry into a table of the the VC1. This works. However, I have someProblamaticUILabel in VC2 that I wish to display "Add Mode." I try to set it in in the segue but this does not work.

If the user then touches the table cell they created in VC1, I want the same VC2 to be used but I want to change the someProblamaticUILabel to read "Edit Mode." This does not work.

I have these wired up using the storyboard.

**Below is some choice output**

```
  From Segue of VC1
     segue.destinationViewController: AppVC2: <AppVC2: 0x146b5f40>
     AppVC2.someProblamaticUILabel: (null)
     AppVC2.someProblamaticUILabel.text: (null)
  From viewDidLoad of VC2: <AppVC2: 0x146b5f40>
     AppVC2 someFunctionalAttribute: edit
     AppVC2 someProblamaticUILabel: <UILabel: 0x1454efc0; frame = (16 20; 151 54); text = 'Add/Edit'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x1454ef50>>
     AppVC2 someProblamaticUILabel.text: Add/Edit
```

**Some code**

//VC1

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AddHomePlayerSegue" ]){
        AppVC2 * addHome = (AppVC2 *) segue.destinationViewController;
        [addHome setDelegate:self];
        addHome.teamType = HOME_TEAM;
        addHome.mode = ADD_MODE;
        addHome.someProblamaticUILabel.text = @"Add";

    }else if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"EditVisitorPlayerSegue" ]){
        AppVC2 * editVisitor = (AppVC2 *) segue.destinationViewController;
        [editVisitor setDelegate:self];
        editVisitor.mode = EDIT_MODE;
        editVisitor.someProblamaticUILabel.text = @"Edit";

        NSLog(@"\n  From Segue of VC1");
        NSLog(@"\n     segue.destinationViewController: AppVC2: %@", editVisitor);
        NSLog(@"\n     AppVC2.someProblamaticUILabel: %@", editVisitor.someProblamaticUILabel);
        NSLog(@"\n     AppVC2.someProblamaticUILabel.text: %@", editVisitor.someProblamaticUILabel.text);
    }
}
```

// VC2

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"\n  From viewDidLoad of VC2: %@", self);
    NSLog(@"\n     AppVC2 someFunctionalAttribute: %@", self.mode);
    NSLog(@"\n     AppVC2 someProblamaticUILabel: %@", self.someProblamaticUILabel);
    NSLog(@"\n     AppVC2 someProblamaticUILabel.text: %@", self.someProblamaticUILabel.text);
}
```

**One more question**
What is the best way to tell VC2 that the user tapped x row with y data to be populated from VC1 to VC2?

Comment: i think the labels are not initialized at this point, you may want to set a property on the destination vc, then in its viewDidLoad set the uilabels text to the property's value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue probably comes from the fact that when you try to set the text property on your UILabel, it has not been inited yet. The `prepareForSegue:` method is called before the transition, so before anything is loaded from your storyboard, and before the call of `viewDidLoad` on your VC2.

Try this :

• Remove the two lines `addHome.someProblamaticUILabel.text = @".....";` from your `prepareForSegue:` method.

• In VC2, in the method `viewDidLoad`, test `self.mode` and set the label according to this value :

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if ([self.mode isEqualToString:ADD_MODE]) self.someProblamaticUILabel.text = @"Add";
    else if ([self.mode isEqualToString:EDIT_MODE]) self.someProblamaticUILabel.text = @"Edit";
    else self.someProblamaticUILabel.text = @"Unknown";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the sequence of methods, in which they are called.

Firstly, there will be

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SEGUE_IDENTIFIER"];
```

Secondly,the **viewDidLoad** of your destination view controller will get called.

Thirdly, **prepareForSegue** in your first view controller will get called up.

Instead of checking the properties in **viewDidLoad** of destination view controller, try to log them in **viewDidAppear** of your destination view controller.

Hope this helps..